# The crystal report display blank page in the first time

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I installed [cr2008sp1.zip](https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100007597732011E/cr2008sp1.zip) in my computer(Win XP) and my server(Win Server 2003). In my computer the report run well in VS2008 and IIS. But in my server, the reportviewer get a error: display blank page, unusual in that the first display is blank, but navigate to next page, the report visible, then i navigate to return page 1, the report is still visible normally. It only hidden in the first.

Answer (score 0):

here is the same problem, some suggestions and the solution to his case (which seems to me the same you have)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1253273.aspx/1

Final solution:
*"I found the solution, i suppressed the report header and blank page is gone..."*

VS2008 and IIS. Is the report viewer the windows form version or the web viewer one?

If you are using a web report viewer maybe the problem is related to IE. Probably the IE version for Windows Server 2003 has different settings than the one in XP

Comment: Unusual in that I install in a another server, it display normally. And only this server get above error. I don't understand.

Comment: as usual... i see u mention VS2008 and IIS. Is the report viewer the windows form version or the web viewer one?

Comment: It's ASP.NET website, using C#. Zoom, navigate page, but refresh, it will display normally. It only error in the first display.

Comment: did you check that the IE internet settings are the same between the XP and the Server2003? maybe that could be interfering... if not i don't know... did u google your problem already?

Comment: In the Server 2003, i run website in localhost is fine, but I tried on several client machines access to the server and have this error.